# how to write C code for arduino to use a screen

Tags: c, arduino, structure

I'm using an arduino MKZERO in order to program it to use a screen of different menu and pages to control a GPS configuration each menu has many items.  I have 4 physical buttons( UP, DOWN,BACK,SELECT)

For the screen I'm using an array of structures, each array is a page.

Is my code designed the right way?
Is there any major issues you could point?

```
    typedef enum {
     IDM_MAIN=0,    
     IDM_FIX_MODE, 
     IDM_MOBILE_MODE, 
     IDM_LAST_SETTING, 
     IDM_POSITION=11, 
     IDM_RESET, 
     IDM_YOUR_COORDINATES=21, 
     IDM_APPLY_LAST_SETTING=31, 
     IDM_OLD_POSITION=111, 
     IDM_NEW_POSITION, 
     IDM_APPLY_RESET=121,
     IDM_LAST_SETTING_CONFIRMED=131, 
     IDM_APPLY_OLD_POSITION=1111, 
     IDM_NAME=2111, 
     IDM_X, 
     IDM_Y, 
     IDM_Z,  
     IDM_RESET_CONFIRMED = 1211,
    IDM_OLD_POSITION_CONFIRMED = 11111
  }t_page;

    typedef struct 
{
  t_page next_page;
  void function(void);   // function to apply somthing if i chose this item
}t_ITEM_MODE; 

typedef struct { 
   t_page page;
   char page_title[20];
   t_page parent_page;
   t_ITEM_MODE item[10];
}t_PAGE;

int N=50;  
t_PAGE screen[N] = {
   //enum page, page_title[], enum parent_page,Item item[{item1}, {item2}]   
  //0  
  [  IDM_MAIN , "PRINCIPAL MENU", IDM_MAIN,[ {IDM_FIX_MODE, NULL }, {IDM_MOBILE_MODE, NULL }, {IDM_LAST_SETTING, NULL}  ]         ],     // t_page1
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. Apart from that, what makes you suspect that somethig is wrong with it? Can you provide a [mre] which demonstrates that? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The function pointer declaration should be `void (*function)(void);` and you need to replace all the `[ ]` in the last line with `{ }`.

Comment: When you have such a doubt, you should first compile your code with all warnings turned on (How depends on the tool you use). Then then modify your code until there is no more warning nor any error. If you cannot suppress a warning or error yourself, then ask for help with a **specific** question about that and a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).